# Flexisel force <li> to one line, not display:inline-block or whites-space:nowrap

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement a flexisel slider into my site.  So I'm trying to line up my li elements to one line, even though there are too many to fit on one line (that's the point of the slider, it will slide them into view).  Right now, the images wrap, so when the slider slides, there's nothing actually to the right, the other images are below it.

Here is my html - nothing special here.

```
<div id="abovedees">
    <div id="flexiselcontainer">
        <ul id="slider">
            <li><%= image_tag('/images/headerimage1.png')%></li>
            <li><%= image_tag('/images/headerimage2.png')%></li>
            <li><%= image_tag('/images/headerimage3.png')%></li>
            <li><%= image_tag('/images/headerimage4.png')%></li>
            <li><%= image_tag('/images/headerimage5.png')%></li>
            <li><%= image_tag('/images/headerimage2.png')%></li>
            <li><%= image_tag('/images/headerimage3.png')%></li>
            <li><%= image_tag('/images/headerimage4.png')%></li>
            <li><%= image_tag('/images/headerimage5.png')%></li>
            <li><%= image_tag('/images/headerimage5.png')%></li>
            <li><%= image_tag('/images/headerimage2.png')%></li>
            <li><%= image_tag('/images/headerimage3.png')%></li>
            <li><%= image_tag('/images/headerimage4.png')%></li>
            <li><%= image_tag('/images/headerimage5.png')%></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
```

and my CSS

```
#flexiselcontainer ul {
    height:200px;
    width:100% !important;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
} 

li {
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.nbs-flexisel-container {
    position:relative;
    max-width:100%;
}

.nbs-flexisel-ul {
    position:relative;
    width:99999px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;   
    text-align:center;  
}

.nbs-flexisel-inner {
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    width:100%;

    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;  
}

.nbs-flexisel-item {
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    line-height:0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
}
.nbs-flexisel-item img {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    max-width:188px;
    max-height:188px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:inline;
}
```

As you can see, I tried the display:inline-block; and white-space:nowrap in more places than I should have but still didn't get the result I needed. The images still overflow to the next line.

Let me know what I'm doing wrong. I appreciate the help!

Edit: been playing with floats: to no avail...

Thanks guys!
Pat

Comment: While editing your code, I noticed you got an extra `}` after your `li{ }` CSS. I've removed it, and it might've been causing you issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot more css there then you're using in the html (no `.nbs-flexisel-ul` class to be seen for example), so I am quite a bit confused, but at the least let me provide you with a minimal setup for what you want. Just copy it in and add all the things you want one by one.

## HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="block"></div></li>
    <li><div class="block"></div></li>
    <li><div class="block"></div></li>
    <li><div class="block"></div></li>
    <li><div class="block"></div></li>
    <li><div class="block"></div></li>
    <li><div class="block"></div></li>
    <li><div class="block"></div></li>
    <li><div class="block"></div></li>
    <li><div class="block"></div></li>
</ul>
```

## CSS

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:auto;
}
li{
    display:inline-block;
}
.block{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin:10px;
    background:black;
}
```

And a JSFiddle link to [see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/wUPV7/1/).